# How to communicate between client device and webserver?

Tags: python, django, networking, raspberry-pi

I've build a little device based on the raspberry pi. Now I want to configure it using my web server. The idea is that I enter all the details on my django web page and then the device just pulls that off the server.

But there are two problems I'm not sure how to solve:

1. I have multiple devices for multiple users so some kind of Login must be provided.
2. The device also sends pictures from time to time. Right now it's using FTP with a general login, but I want to personalize that too for every device. The uploads will need a resume function so http is out!

So the basic question is: Should I get started with sockets or is there a better and safer way to do it? Maybe there is some kind of open source library that's been tested a lot?

Comment: What OS do you have on your raspberry pi? Can it simply fetch data from your web server over https?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hand coding sockets, I would suggest using HTTP with BASIC authentication to communicate between the device and the web server. You can uniquely assign an id/pwd to each device, and BASIC authentication is well supported by all web servers and client side libraries.

There are some security [concerns](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https) with BASIC authentication even if you use HTTPS, but it maybe acceptable in your particular case here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use **SSH**, with **Fabric** for instance. [Here](http://python-for-system-administrators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssh.html) an example.